# Unmarshall part of XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have this XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:listItemsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.ws.server.wst.fit.cvut.cz/">
            <return>
                <code>OK</code>
                <data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:type="ns2:items">
                    <item>
                        <itemId>1540041177</itemId>
                        <price>5109</price>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <itemId>696734629</itemId>
                        <price>5453</price>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <itemId>1853843391</itemId>
                        <price>5088</price>
                    </item>
                </data>
            </return>
        </ns2:listItemsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I want to unmarshall the `data` element to my POJO (not the whole XML, just the part of it). Is it possible with JAXB?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
public class Data {

    private List<Item> items;

    public Data() {
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [" + (items != null ? "items=" + items : "") + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a StAX `XMLStreamReader` to advance to the content you are interested in and then unmarshal that.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: @Tomas - Give the StAX approach a try.  You will find much better performance and memory usage than DOM.  The link points to a full example.

Comment: But I need to traverse the DOM to check for some elements and then use the unmarshalling... Anyway, I accepted your answer because it's more general than mine

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I'm using DOM. But I found the solution

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()));
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

and when I'm traversing over nodes in document, then I can simply (when I have the node I want)

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Data data = (Data) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(node);
```